# Microsoft Access Color code conversion Logic to RGB or HEX or DEC value

Tags: java, colors

I have an MS Acess Colour code . I want to convert the color to RGB or HEX  or DEC.
How to convert it using java .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to convert MS Access Color code to Hex Code :

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder;

class Test {
private static final int sizeOfIntInHalfBytes = 8;
private static final int numberOfBitsInAHalfByte = 4;
private static final int halfByte = 0x0F;
private static final char[] hexDigits = { 
'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', 
'8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'
};
private static String finalHexCode;

private static String decToHex(int dec) {
StringBuilder hexBuilder = new StringBuilder(sizeOfIntInHalfBytes);
hexBuilder.setLength(sizeOfIntInHalfBytes);
for (int i = sizeOfIntInHalfBytes - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
  int j = dec & halfByte;
  hexBuilder.setCharAt(i, hexDigits[j]);
  dec >>= numberOfBitsInAHalfByte;
}
return hexBuilder.toString(); 
}

public static String FinalHex(int dec) {
  String ReversedHex = decToHex(dec);
  if(ReversedHex.length() != 0)
      finalHexCode = "#"+ReversedHex.substring(6, 8)+ReversedHex.substring(4, 6)+ReversedHex.substring(2, 4);
  return finalHexCode; 
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this , however i have already seen this.. I want to know  the logic for converting the ms access color code

Comment: @SureshBora I know `C#` way to convert Microsoft Access Color code to Hex. if you need, i can post it.

Comment: @Arshad Parwez I have seen that code.. It is very easy to convert using c# ,well i did not get the logic happening there . however if you know what logic is happening there you can post that  It will be helpfull

Comment: @SureshBora : try this code and use in your main class : Test.FinalHex(<Access code>);

Comment: @ArshadParwez Wow  work like charm... thanks it is the only i was looking for.. save my day ..:)

Comment: @SureshBora : Glad I cud help u

Answer (score 2):

The example by Arshu seems like it would work well, but seems to have a lot of code, and it could be confusing to those who have no idea what's going on.

I found an example here http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/bgr-color-to-java-color.126668/ that is old, but seems to work for what I need thus far.

A full working example

```
import java.awt.Color;

/**
 *
 * @author Konrad
 */
public class colortest
{

    public static Color convert(int BGRColorNumber)
    {
//color codes as a int in form "BGR"
return new Color((BGRColorNumber & 0xFF),
((BGRColorNumber >> 8) & 0xFF),
((BGRColorNumber >> 16) & 0xFF));
}

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Color convert = colortest.convert(16777215);
        System.out.println(convert);
    }

}

//colornum = 16777215; //pure white
//colornum = 255; //pure red
//colornum = 65280; //pure green
//colornum = 16711680; //pure blue
```

Output: java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255] aka pure white.

You can find color codes all over, so there is more testing to be done, but this seems to suffice.

I have used something similar in a chroma key project I was working on.